# Android 4.x Bluetooth issues with low freq. headset profile changed! why?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, headset

We are using application which get low frequency audio signal from HFP
BT point. We have used Android version 3.xx which work fine. and the
BT point was define as headset point
When we have upgrade the android version to 4.xx the BT point is
define as audio phone and the low frequency are being cut out. We
didn"t find anyway to define the BT point as headset.

1. Is there any way to define BT point as headset in android 4.xx
2. Can we upload the Android 3.xx BT stack to android 4.xx

thanks

Comment: I assume you mean 'upgrade' the Android 3.xx BT stack to Android 4.xx.  Keep in mind that your version of Bluetooth depends on the hardware: you can't get bt4 unless you have a bt4 radio.